# Excel migrate to database design

Tags: database-design

I have many tables that exactly mirror Excel sheets.

For example

Excel

```
Region  Year    Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     July    Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
North   2008    100     200     400     600     800     900     180     290     720     900     400     120
South   2008    100     300     600     900     899     900     300     900     300     900     100     200
...
```

I would rather not store the above excel sheet in the database .

But people are asking me why?

Why not store it exactly like Excel as the number of rows would be fewer and performance faster?

How do I convince that storing with fewer columns is a better design?

Like the one below:

I am using many RDBMS like Sybase, Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL

```
Region  Year    Month   Profit
North   2008    Jan     100
South   2008    Jan     100.
North   2008    Feb     200
South   2008    Mar     400
...
```

I feel the above design is elegant and that's what I have seen every other place I have been, but people at my current assignment want the table to be Excel like.

How do I convince them that mirroring Excel design into database is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd want to find out who'll be entering/modifying/querying data, and how they'll perform such operations (eg, writing actual SQL, using Excel as a front-end, some other fill-in-the-black application, etc).

If the users will be writing any SQL I'm guessing you'll have a much easier time selling them on the relational model based on how much coding they'll have to do.  Take for example a search of months where Profit > 350:

```
-- excel-like structure

select Region, Year, 'Jan' as Month, Jan as Profit from excel_table where Jan > 350
union all
select Region, Year, 'Feb' as Month, Feb as Profit from excel_table where Feb > 350
union all
select Region, Year, 'Mar' as Month, Mar as Profit from excel_table where Mar > 350
union all
... and on and on and on and on ...

-- relational structure

select Region, Year, Month, Profit
from relation_table
where Profit > 350
```

Another tedious example for the excel_table: adding a new Profit value for each month (as it becomes available).

Once you get them used to writing lots of queries with separate where clauses for each month, you can point out how performance could be degraded if you don't have indices on each 'month' column, which in turn could mean more db space usage, possibly less room in cache for data, and potentially longer times to insert/update/delete data (due to updating more indexes).

---

The one drawback to the relational model will of course be the display of the data to look like the excel spreadsheet.

If the users will be writing their own code then they'll have to jump through some hoops to build a pivot table (ie, turn a month/profit row into a column).

Then again, this may not be as much of a problem if their front-end/application can handle this for them ... ?